# specific way to trigger a significant location change event with simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator

Im debugging an app that makes use of significant location change events.

With recent xcode updates, the normal method of "change the location to a custom location" does not work. Instead, you have to toggle back and forth between a movement setting and None until it starts working -- then from there, only in setting it on a movement setting will it trigger a new location change event.

This is a well-known bug that is active on the developer support forums at apple.

It leads to the question -- is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I used to be able to trigger location updates just by keeping the simulator on "Freeway Drive" and it triggers every couple of minutes. It doesn't seem to be doing that anymore. Have you found a better way to simulate this since you posted your question?

Comment: So , the problem for me was that the simulator is kinda buggy. Close the debugging execution, kill the simulator processes from the commandline, and then restart debugging.

Comment: yep that worked, thanks!

Comment: Hey @KDaker, please consider giving me a vote up then? I've added this response as the answer to me question so others can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So , the problem for me was that the simulator is kinda buggy. Close the debugging execution, kill the simulator processes from the commandline, and then restart debugging.

Comment: This actually worked. but just quitting simulator so it reboots on next launch was enough didn't need command line. `launchOptions` nil is a new problem though.